# AZURE: How to view all code files with Azure

Tags: azure, magento, azure-web-app-service, magento2, magento-2.3

Does anyone have an idea about how to view all code files and databases with the Azure portal or CLI?

I am a first time user for AZURE, If anyone knows about the step by step process please help me.

We are using "Magento on Kubernetes + Docker Images" we have installed the Magento with following this [link](https://www.magemodule.com/all-things-magento/magento-2-tutorials/docker-magento-2-development/) but how to access my code files.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly, you are referring to managing the site file(s) for your Azure App Service WebApp or let me know if it is something else.
Just to highlight, when you provision an Azure WebApp, it assigns a subdomain of azurewebsites.net.

Checkout the documentations for more details on the process:

**[deploy-continuous-deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment)**

**[Deployment Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/deploy-best-practices)**

There are several ways to manage the files:

Navigate to your Azure WebApp from the Portal.

1. Use Kudu console (https://yoursite.scm.azurewebsites.net)
2. Checkout App Service ‘Console’ option
3. Leverage App Service Editor

[image]

Kindly let me know if you need additional information on this topic.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But we are using "Magento on Kubernetes + Docker Images" we have install the magento but how to access my code files..

Comment: Could you please share the link to the article/template which you leveraged (Or/& a screenshot)? conceal any private details before posting on the public forum.